How to link a 2D map from the game to the program
There is a 2d card consisting of several colors. The red dot on the map is the person with the direction. It is necessary that the person moves only along a certain color (in this example, only along white paths).
I don't understand how to get information from photos. In theory, the algorithm should receive an image and orient the person along the paths

I'm guessing this question is related to neural networks.

It's not about neural networks or deep learning at all.  If that's truly the model of the image (grayscale except for the arrow), it's very easy to scan the image and find out where the red blob is.

How to scan the image?

What image library are you using?  Most of them have a way to treat the image as an array of pixels.

I am using pillow. But how it can help me to orient person on the map

There are multiple ways to achieve your goal. Below I've created simple example of transition image to game. I've used PIL lib to parse image and pyxel as a game engine.
import pyxel
from PIL import Image

BORDER_OFFSET = 5
STEP = 5
COLOR_ROAD = (255, 255, 255, 255)
COLOR_PLAYER = (237, 28, 36, 255)


def parse_image():
    road = []
    img = Image.open('image.png')
    pix = img.load()
    width, height = img.size
    x = 0
    y = 0
    player = None
    for y in range(BORDER_OFFSET, height-BORDER_OFFSET, STEP):
        for x in range(BORDER_OFFSET, width-BORDER_OFFSET, STEP):
            color = pix[x, y]
            if color == COLOR_ROAD:
                road.append((x, y))
            elif color == COLOR_PLAYER:
                player = (x, y)
    return x, y, player, road


class Game:
    def __init__(self):
        width, height, self.player, self.road = parse_image()
        pyxel.init(width, height)
        pyxel.run(self.update, self.draw)

    def update(self):
        pass

    def draw(self):
        pyxel.cls(pyxel.COLOR_BLACK)
        for c in self.road:
            pyxel.circ(c[0], c[1], 10, pyxel.COLOR_WHITE)
        pyxel.circ(self.player[0], self.player[1], 30, pyxel.COLOR_RED)


Game()



Thanks. It is a good aproach
